# changing the browser address bar / window color

Tags: web-app, dashboard

I'm looking for a solution for a dashboard.

Users will be able to see the dashboard in the "see as other user" mode (they can see someones else dashboard). For that I need solution to clearly indicate that somebody is displaying dashboard as a different person.

I was thinking about some yellow frame outside the whole dashboard, something like prompt for user administration rights in windows. Recently I've came up with an idea to have whole browser in different color like IE 'In Private' mode like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do such thing in IE / Chrome ? Maybe some other good solutions for that ?

Comment: Are you asking on how to implement this, or how it should look like?

Comment: Is this a UX or implementation question?

Comment: I mean what will be the best to indicate so how should it look like. Also if anybody have idea if the way I've described it is possible to implement I'd be grateful for the answers.

Comment: Are you referring to something like the theme-color meta tag for Chrome for Android? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android?hl=en
However, I don't think there are any desktop browsers that support this.

Comment: IF you could change the [**browser chrome**](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/38972/browser-chrome) (what the broswer border area is called) I imagine that would suffice but I doubt this is possible. I would think having a splash screen display saying "you are now entering 'whoevers' dashboard" and then a box in the corner with an eye icon and text saying "see as other mode".

Comment: I'm reffering to somethin exact like theme color meta for chrome on android. Unfortunately haven't found anything like this for desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a web-based or desktop-based application?

I couldn't speak to the technical feasibility of implementing an alternative color chrome on the desktop, but in the web world I think you would be limited to modifying the environment within the web page.

It sounds like your goal is to ensure that the user understands that they are working 'as' someone else in a given window. A common pattern for addressing this it to fix an alert interface to the top of the viewport. This solution means that a bar of significant contrast is always visible as the user scrolls - you may want to include/modify addition cues to vary the extent to which the user is conscious of that UI depending on how critical it is that they remain conscious of the bar.  For example, for more critical environments, you may make the text and/or bar larger, brighter, you may add a drop-shadow such that it sits above the page, you may add an icon with i.e. an exclamation mark to ensure the user remains aware.

You could also put a border of the same high-contrast, warning colour (i.e. red, or amber) all the way around the page to further emphasise the point.

Is that the sort of suggestions you were after?

Comment: This is web-based app. Thank you for your suggestions. I think I will go with the highly visible border on whole dashboard. My goal with that is exactly make users aware that they are working 'as' someone else in a given window